# Does ObjectBox assign negative IDs?

Tags: android, objectbox

I want to check for valid IDs. Should I check for `id > 0 || id < -1` or just `id > 0`?

The documentation just states that 0 and -1 are reserved and that the next ID will be higher then the highest present ID, with an example starting at 1. Is it just an example or can we rely on that?

Comment: It sounds like the IDs are auto-generated. Why are you trying to validate them?

Comment: e.g. to prevent `Database.boxFor(clazz).get(id)` from crashing my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid ID is `id > 0 || id < -1` or `id != 0 && id != -1`.

The first IDs are always 1, 2, 3, ...

If you have IDs 1,2,3,4,5 and delete 4 and 5, new IDs may or may not reuse 4 and 5. You should not rely on that behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear with respect to the initial question and because no example shows it: IDs may also be negative. So `-2` is a valid ID.
(Not a question - just a supplement.)